# Trying to plot a figure similar to one found in a publication using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to generate a figure that looks like the third/bottom portion of this figure (where there are French/Sardinian as Y and others as X)
http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v514/n7523/fig_tab/nature13810_F3.html

I know I need to use ggplot2 to generate these but I don't have an idea how. I was wondering if someone could help

This is my rudimentary code

```
tbl$RegionX2 <- factor(tbl$RegionX, as.character(tbl$RegionX))
plot <- ggplot(tbl, aes(y = RegionX2, 
            x = D, xmin = D - 2*SE, xmax = D + 2*SE, label = RegionX2, colour = RegionY)) + 
    geom_point(colour = "black") + 
  geom_text(hjust = 1.2) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        legend.position = "none") + 
  geom_errorbarh(height = 0)
ggsave(plot=plot,height=7,width=7, filename="figure.pdf", useDingbats=FALSE)
```

But I don't know how to keep Region A and B from stacking on top of eachother, to get the x=0 line, or to get the X and Y labels as they are in that figure. Can anyone help?

Also, my data is formatted as such:

```
RegionX RegionY D   SE
Region1 A   -0.02   4.2E-03
Region2 A   -0.03   3.1E-03
Region3 A   0.04    2.8E-03
Region4 A   0.05    5.7E-03
Region5 A   0.06    2.8E-03
Region6 B   -0.065  2.4E-03
Region7 B   -0.07   3.8E-03
Region8 B   0.08    2.6E-03
Region9 B   0.09    1.1E-03
RegionA B   0.095   1.5E-03
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't very clear what you intend to achieve but after having a look at your expected figure from the link, here is something I was able to produce. Hope this is helpful.

First I created a new column using the RegionY and RegionX, so that unique factors can be placed on Y axis. Here is how it was done. `tbl` is the dataframe from your dataset.

```
tbl$X <- paste0(tbl$RegionY,tbl$RegionX)
```

---

```
tbl$X <- as.factor(tbl$X)
```

then here is the plotting

```
  ggplot(tbl, aes(y = X,x = D,fill=RegionY)) + 
  geom_point(shape=21) + 
  scale_y_discrete(limits=rev(levels(tbl$X)),label=rev(substring(tbl$X,1,1))) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  geom_text(aes(label=tbl$RegionX,colour=RegionY),x=0.02) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-0.04,0.025)) + 
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = D - 2*SE, xmax = D + 2*SE,colour=RegionY),height=0.4) +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")
```